# Cmake files detection

Tags: python, cmake

I have a sub-directory in which i have my python files for compilation
I added a new file and accidentally forgot to add it to **CMakeList.txt**
The problem is that the build was successful. 
My question is does **CMake** detect automatically all the files in the indicated sub-directory? or does it detect any files that have dependencies with other files added to **CmakeList.txt**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any file should be **explicitely** mentioned in `CMakeLists.txt` in some way for track its changes in CMake.

That is why using `GLOB()` command for collect sources is not recommended: CMake will not detect automatically whether new source file has been added.

Comment: turns out that there was something wrong with my environment. when I did full clean, The result make sense as the build fail if i don't add all the files to Cmake. Thanks for the clarification